# Zend Framework-CE installation: how on a shared host?

Tags: php, zend-framework

When I try to install the main Zen Server (Deb/RPM installer script...the only thing provided for linux) onto my bluehost account, I get this error:

Unable to install: Your distribution is not suitable for installation using
Zend's DEB/RPM repositories. You can install Zend Server Community Edition on
most Linux distributions using the generic tarball installer. For more 
information, see http://www.zend.com/en/community/zend-server-ce

Which ultimately, leads right back to the same download page.  I am puzzled on what to do next.

Bluehost uses a version of linux of some sort and PHP 5.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a tarball installer either, or much documentation about it with the latest version.  The [current documentation](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/zend-server-community-edition.htm#choosing_which_distribution_to_install.htm) doesn't say anything about non deb/rpm installers and for the supported OS'es only shows debs or rpms.  They may not offer a tarball version anymore but I don't know for sure.

If you are on shared hosting, you may be able to successfully install ZendServer-CE but you will be unable to run it as the Apache server and Zend Server have to bind to ports on the system which only a privileged user can do.  Zend Server installs its own version of Apache and PHP, as well as the Zend Server manager which manages those instances.  Such software can only be run by the root user on the system, which I am guessing your shared account is not.

You would however be able to install ZS-CE on your local machine, or you can download the Virtual Development Server from the [Zend Studio Download](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads) page.  I believe the Virtual Development Server comes pre-loaded with Zend Server CE and Zend Studio.

Comment: A clear misunderstanding on my part.  Zend server is not what I wanted which was what I was trying to desparately download.  Thanks for pointing that out, ZF works just fine on my host now.

Answer (score 2):

The installation script install_zs.sh looks in /etc/issue for a list of supported operating systems.  Edit install_zs.sh and add your OS name (found in /etc/issue) to the SUPPORTED_OS variable.

For example, Amazon's default machine image for EC2 has "Amazon Linux AMI" in /etc/issue.  My install_zs.sh now looks like this.

SUPPORTED_OS='Amazon Linux AMI|CentOS|Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server|Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server|Fedora|SUSE|Debian GNU/Linux|Ubuntu|Oracle Linux Server'

Answer (score -1):

The Zend installation script is grepping /etc/issue for the list of valid OSs.  You can either add "CentOS" (or something) to /etc/issue or comment out the check in the installation script.

Comment: nice if add it ass comment.